# Using “foram” ― is this correct across subjunctives and use

Tags: modo-subjuntivo

> Podem fazer-se mudanças sempre que foram dentro de 15 mil dólares e não fossem de atividades que foram a salários.

In English:

> Changes can be made as long as they are within 15 thousand dollars and they were activities and did not go to salaries.

Comment: What do you think? We are not supposed to do editing but help you understand some point or other. sempre que introduces doubt or uncertainty so the subjunctive is right here.

Comment: Clayton, I am sorry, but it is hard to understand what you are trying to say. Could you please make it clearer? If that helps, try reading other questions here written in English, so you can understand the format.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I was not clear in my question - main doubt is here: não fossem de atividades que foram a salários. You see how forem appears twice but is not in subjunctive the second time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence is not quite right. You want one of these:

> Podem fazer-se mudanças **sempre que sejam** abaixo de 15 mil dólares e **sejam** atividades que não  **vão** para salários.
>
> Podem fazer-se mudanças **sempre que forem** abaixo de 15 mil dólares e **forem** atividades que não **forem** para salários.

Because you’re talking of hypothetical, potential, changes, you need the subjunctive, either present (*sejam*) or future (*forem*): both work in this case; the present subjunctive of *ir* is *vão*, and the future subjunctive of both *ir* and *ser* is *forem*.

Now, if instead of *sempre que* (more akin to *whenever*) you use *desde que* (more akin to your *as long as*) then you can only use the present subjunctive, not the future subjunctive (the choice between the two often depends on little things like this), but without any change in meaning:

> Podem fazer-se mudanças **desde que sejam** abaixo de 15 mil dólares e **sejam** atividade que não  **vão** para salários.

What you don’t want is the past subjunctive *fossem*, because that’s for counterfactuals, as in:

> Poderiam fazer-se as mudanças se elas **fossem** para actividades… mas como **não são**, não se fazem (changes could be made if they were for activities… but as they are not, they are not made)

If you were talking of changes that have happened already then you could use the indicative, but I’d use the “pretérito imperfeito” (*eram, íam*), not the “pretérito perfeito” (*foram*):

> Poderam fazer-se as mudanças sempre que **eram** abaixo de 15 mil dólares e **eram** atividades que não **íam** para salários.

The notion of “activities that go to salaries” sounds strange to me, but I cannot suggest anything better without understanding exactly what you mean. But it is *para* not *a* (and I’m Portuguese, hence rather partial towards *a* when compared to Brazilians).